# How to get the content of remote notification using FCM (iOS)?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM for sending a push notification to devices using this method

```
 func push(message: String, toUser: String) {
    var token: String?
    for person in self.users {
        if toUser == person.username && person.firebaseToken != nil {
            token = person.firebaseToken
        }
    }
    if token != nil {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("key=[your FCM Server Key]", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        let json = [
            "to" : token!,
            "priority" : "high",
            "notification" : [
                "body" : message
            ]
        ] as [String : Any]
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted)
            request.httpBody = jsonData
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                    print("Error=\(error)")
                    return
                }

                if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                    // check for http errors
                    print("Status Code should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                    print("Response = \(response)")
                }

                let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                print("responseString = \(responseString)")
            }
            task.resume()
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

But the devices are just getting the message without doing anything with it.
I am trying to save the content of it, too. How can I do that? Is the only option to save it to the Firebase database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to handle notifications through the AppDelegate. You'll first register for the notifications in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Because firebase doesnt have a key when it first starts up for messaging, you'll need to register to observe that value as well:

```
    // register for remote notifications:
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: { (_, _) in })
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }


    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.firInstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil, queue: nil, using: tokenRefreshNotification(_:))
```

and then you'll need a method to connect to FCM:

```
extension AppDelegate {
    func connectToFCM() {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("unable to connect to FCM \(error)")
            } else {
                print("connected to FCM")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And a way to handle when you get a new token:

```
extension AppDelegate {
    func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(refreshedToken, forKey: "registrationToken")
        }

        connectToFCM()
    }
}
```

Lastly, you'll need to actually handle the notification. The actual content of the push notification is in the 'notification' object for iOS 10 and higher:

```
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        PushService.handle(userInfo) // do whatever you need with this

    }
}
```

And to handle the other types of notifications, you fall back to the old way:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    //user tapped on notification
    PushService.handle(userInfo) // do what you need with the userInfo dict here, which contains the push notification information

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how much time the notification will remain if the device didn't get it? If I send notification that says "123" and the other device is closed and then I open it after a week will the app will get the push? Or if the app is open, is it still going to call those function for saving the data?

Comment: After the notification is received on the device it remains on the device until the application opens again. If the application was backgrounded, it'll call didReceieveRemoteNotification, or the ios 10 equivalent (userNotificationCenter), but if the app was closed then the push notification payload will be contained in the 'options' of application(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)